# Is there any way to sort different pages of Microsoft word file by number appearing at specific place in every page

Tags: microsoft-word

Every page of word file looks like this

```
Xxxx
Xxx
Xxx

32A: xxxxxx1234

Xxx
Xxxx
Xxxxx
```

Different Numbers appear in place of 1234 in different pages.Can pages be sorted by this number.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. 
What I would suggest, since I don't know the extent of the work you need to do, to transfer all the information into an Excel sheet and create a new file with the sorting of your choosing using the populate feature

Comment: See "Word Doesn't Know What a Page Is" by Word MVP Daiya Mitchell. https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html That remains as true today as it was when it was written. You will need something else to delimit the area you want to use in your sort. Word understands words, paragraphs and sections, but not pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would attack this problem in two steps:

1. Assign the pages bookmarks that contain these strings,
2. Sort the pages via their bookmarks.

Step 1 can be done manually. If there are too many pages,
you could create a keyboard+mouse macro using a product such
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
(on Windows) to make it easier.

Step 2 can be done by Adobe Acrobat with the AutoBookmark plug-in
(trial versions available).
A detailed description is found in the Adobe article
[Arranging PDF Pages Using Bookmarks](https://www.evermap.com/Tutorial_ABM_ArrangingPagesUsingBookmarks.asp).